Self-referential, numeric crossword
This puzzle is inspired by this amazing puzzle.
In this crossword, every solution is a unique positive integer. Ignore spaces and dashes (e. g. 285 would be entered as TWOHUNDREDEIGHTYFIVE.) In addition, the clues are scrambled up, but I've given you which ones are across and which are down; hopefully that should help.
Three more things before I give the grid and clues:
First, I've made the placements into letters so as to not cause further numerical confusion.
Second, references to other clues' numbers are indicated using the other clue's position in parentheses, like this: (a).
Finally, I also always use "th" when referring to ordinal numbers (e. g. (a)th); this doesn't necessarily mean that (a) in this case can't end in 1 or 2 due to improper grammar.
Good luck!

ACROSS

(d)th prime
(c) squared
The cube root of (o)
Magic number for a magic square of size (i)
Relatively prime with every other number in the puzzle, except (j)
Number used in a sports team’s name, minus (l)
(m)th decimal digit of pi
(n- DOWN)th Fibonacci number
Divisor of (n- ACROSS)

DOWN

Number of Collatz operations for (k) to reach (f- ACROSS)
Divisor of (b)
The number of two-digit numbers in the puzzle
Largest prime smaller than (f- DOWN)
Multiple of the smallest positive integer not in the puzzle
Positive difference between (e) and a low multiple of (g)
A digit contained in (a)
(h)th triangle number


My most recent and still-unsolved puzzle is also inspired by a puzzle of the great Alconja, but I cannot say which one, since that might give it away.

Oh wait is it american spelling or english, think I just realised the discrepancy ^

@BeastlyGerbil I'm American, so I probably used American spelling. Didn't know there was a difference!

Here's how I solved it (not necessarily the most efficient way):
e can be

[1/2/6][01/02/06/10] or [3/7/8]000, but o can't have a D so it must be the first form



k can be

48 or 58, but l can't start with I, so they must be 48 and 1



m can be

2 or 10, but n can't end with O, so it must be 10



n can only be

77



e can be

106, 206, or 606



o can be

64, 65, or 69



j must be

11



d can be

13, 14, 18, or 19



i can be

5 or 9, and f can be 15, 16, or 70, so they must be 5 and 15



f can be

4 or 5, but 5 is already used, so it must be 4



d can be

13 or 14, but c can't end in F, so it must be 13



c must be

8



e can be

106, 206, or 606, but g can't have E or X, so it must be 206



g can be

14, 41, 42, or 46, but h can't start with E, W, or I, so it must be 41



h must be

9



n must be

6



the (h)th triangular number is

45, so this must be b



The magic number for a magic square of size (i) is

65

and the cube of another number in the puzzle must be

64

so these must be

a and o

which finishes the grid:

 

Finally, we can resolve the labels for the clues as follows:
ACROSS

 g. (d)th prime
 o. (c) squared
 f. The cube root of (o)
 a. Magic number for a magic square of size (i)
 n. Relatively prime with every other number in the puzzle, except (j)
 k. Number used in a sports team’s name, minus (l)
 i. (m)th decimal digit of pi
 c. (n- DOWN)th Fibonacci number
 j. Divisor of (n- ACROSS)

DOWN

 h. Number of Collatz operations for (k) to reach (f- ACROSS)
 f. Divisor of (b)
 m. The number of two-digit numbers in the puzzle
 d. Largest prime smaller than (f- DOWN)
 e. Multiple of the smallest positive integer not in the puzzle
 l. Positive difference between (e) and a low multiple of (g)
 n. A digit contained in (a)
 b. (h)th triangle number


Oh damn you sniped me and I didn't even realise, +1! Thats super interesting that you solved in the complete opposite direction to me!

Lovely puzzle!! Heres the solution:

 

With the clues and answers now labelled:

ACROSS

a) - (c) [8] squared = SIXTYFOUR
c) - (n- DOWN)th [6th] Fibonacci number = EIGHT
f) - The cube root of another number in the puzzle [64] = FOUR
g) - (d)th [13th] prime - FORTYONE
i) - (m)th [10th] decimal of pi - FIVE
j) - Divisor of (n-ACROSS) [77] = ELEVEN

DOWN

b) (h)th [9th] triangle number = FORTYFIVE
d) Largest prime smaller than (f- DOWN) [15] = THIRTEEN
e) Multiple of the smallest positive integer not in the puzzle [2'] = TWOHUNDREDSIX
f) Divisor of (b) [45] = FIFTEEN
h) Number of Collatz operations for (k) [48] to reach (f- ACROSS) [4'] = NINE
l) Positive difference between (e) [206] and a low multiple of (g) [205] = ONE
m) The number of two-digit numbers in the puzzle = TEN
n) A digit contained in both (o) [64] and (a) [65] = SIX


How I got there:
To start:

Firstly I focused on the clue:

'Magic number for a magic square of size (i)'

(i) is only four characters long, and as 0 makes no sense that means it is 4, 5 or 9. The magic number for 9x9 magic squares is 369, which is too many characters to fit on the board, so (i) must be 'FOUR' or 'FIVE'

This means, as the magic numbers are 34 and 65 for 4 and 5, the answer is either 9 or 10 characters long. There is no 10 character option, so it must by 65 meaning (i) is FIVE.  Also either (a) or (o) is 'SIXTYFIVE'

Next:

(f) down is 7 letters and has 3rd letter 'f'. The only possible number that could fit is 'FIFTEEN'

There is also a clue that references f-down - 'Largest prime smaller than [15]' which is 'THIRTEEN'. This is 8 characters, which means it must be (d)

Right now the board looks like this:



Now:

(f) across must be 'FOUR', and c across must also be 'EIGHT'

We now have the following answers from other clues:

[13]th prime is 'FORTYONE' (note american spelling)
[8] squared is 'SIXTYFOUR'
Magic number for a magic square of size 5 is 'SIXTYFIVE'

64 and 65 will go in a and o in some order, and 41 must go in (g). However the answer to 'A digit contained in both (o) and (a)' can be solved without placing them and must be 'SIX'

(h) is now 4 letters beginning with 'N' so must be 'NINE'

That means the [9]th triangle number is also 'FORTYFIVE' which must be (b) down.

Updated grid:



We can then:

Deduce e must end in 'SIX', and the o in third means it must begin with 'TWO'. So (e) must be 206 - 'TWOHUNDREDSIX' as that is the only number that fits the number of characters.

The 'Positive difference between (e) and a low multiple of (g)' clue then is  the difference between 205 (41*5) and 206, which is 'ONE'.

(j) now starts with 'E' and ends in 'N' so must be 'ELEVEN'.

An update to the grid:



As we have the 'Cube root of (o)' we can also deduce that (o) is 64, and (a) is 65.

Now to be a little tricky:

(l), (m) and (n) are all 3 character answers (1, 2, 6 or 10). We currently have '1' and '6' to be placed in one of these from the final two clues of the down clues.

We also have k across - as well as the clue 'Number used in a sports team’s name, minus (l)'

Well - 'ONE' would fit well letter wise in (l), and the '49ers' could become '48' which would fit. So (k) is 'FORTYEIGHT' and (l) is 'ONE'

n across can then be 'SEVENTYSEVEN - coprime with everything but 11, and then (m) down is 'TEN'

Finally (n) down is 'SIX' giving the final grid:



Now that the grid is solved the final missing answers can be matched up to the clues and we're done!

